# How do I capitalize first character of sentence?

Tags: java, regex

I need to capitalize first character of a sentence where sentence ends with a period. ( it could be multiple periods too) OR !

```
 String result = "";
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(content);
 scanner.useDelimiter("(?<=(\\.+))|(?<=!)");
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
     String line = scanner.next();
     String line1 = line.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + line.substring(1);
     result = result + line1;
 }
```

When i do this , the whitespace new line character is present at the 0 index and the program doesn't capitalize the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the line:

String line = scanner.next().trim();

Comment: Thanks ! It is close but i need to retain the new line character as well when i write back.

Comment: result = line1 + System.lineSeparator();

Comment: Thanks . It works. Do you know when i use scanner.useDelimiter("(?<=(\\.+)) this why it creates multiple splits for a sentence like " come soon ... Please come back" .  I would expect it to break into two splits but it break each period into a new split.

Comment: What kind of delimiter do you have in mind? Delineate around one exclamation mark or one or more periods?

Comment: Yes, one or more period or exclamation marks . I thought regex (\\.+) should take care of it.

Comment: I do not understand the use of the zero-width positive look-behind. How about “\\s*[!.]+\\s*”

Comment: if i don't use look behind , i don't get to retain the delimiters when i write back my string to a file.

Comment: So add them when you do the write back.

Comment: how would i know what delimiter was used to separate the fields ?

Comment: Oh, you want to retain the diameters and use them as delimiters? "?<=[!.]+” maybe.

Comment: Yes, i want to retain the delimiters and also use them as delimiters to split the sentences. I need to perform some operations when i split them.

Comment: for e.g.     This is coming .... because you said it will !  then lets go... done.         I should expect on splitting using the delimiter and retaining it =>  This is coming ....    2) because you said it will !   3) then lets go .... 4) done.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the split happens left to right, and applies as soon as the conditions are met. You have to tighten the conditions. This works: "(?<=[!.]+)(?![!.])" At least as a string split. Not sure if real-time input to a scanner will behave the same.